# Is R compatible with windows 8.1 64bit edition?

Tags: r

I have installed the latest version of `R` from the official [site](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)

However when I open it it takes some time to open. I have tested it in Windows 7 64bit edition and it opens very fast.

Is there any known and common problem for windows 8.1?

Comment: This would be very surprising.  Maybe antivirus issues?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't have any antivirus in my PC.

Comment: Is this Win8.1 fresh install? Because some of my friends observe longer starting times for every app if they have installed 8.1 some time ago, especially if they did upgrade 8.0 -> 8.1

Comment: I'm using it on Win8.1, both 32bit and 64bit, R-3.1.2, R-3.1.3, with no startup issues. Does `R --vanilla` behave any differently?

Comment: @java_xof it is fresh installed the windows version.

Comment: @r2evans to be honest I I have never heard before for vanilla because I am junior developer in R so I will search for it and come back. thank you both for your comments..

Comment: I don't believe `--vanilla` is something you should be doing on a regular basis (for working in *R*); it is more often used for simple scripts and/or troubleshooting (in times such as this). If this changes things, then you could start looking into each of the options that `--vanilla` implies (e.g., `--no-site-file`, `--no-init-file`, and `--no-environ`) to see if that changes things.